# Compute the norm of a linear bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

> Define $T:(\ell_\infty,||.||_{\infty}) \rightarrow (\mathcal{C}[-1/2,1/2]),||.||_{\infty})$ by $T(x(n))=f(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x(n)s^k$ show that is a continous operator and compute the norm of $T$ ($||T||$)

I prove to $T$ is well defined and bounded (this implies continuity) and i try the next:

Let $s\in [-1/2,1/2]$ then $|s^n|\leq 1/2^n$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$  and
$$||T(x)||_\infty =||\sum_{n=1}^\infty x(n)s^k||_\infty=\sup_{s \in [-1/2,1/2]} |\sum_{n=1}^\infty x(n)s^n| \leq \sup_{s } \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x(n)s^n| \leq ||x||_\infty \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}$$
And therefore
$$ ||T(x)||_\infty \leq 1\cdot||x(n)||_\infty$$
Those i think to $||T||=1$ but i not sure to the last procedement its correct, any suggestion or hit i will very grateful

Comment: Can you find a sequence $x(n)$ such that $||T(x(n))||_\infty /||x(n)||_\infty
 = 1$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\|T\|$ is defined to be the smallest number $C \ge 0$ such that $\|T(x)\|_\infty \le C \|x\|_\infty$ for all sequences $x$. You have proven that $\|T(x)\|_\infty \le \|x\|_\infty$ for all sequences $x$. This shows that $\|T\| \le 1$.

To prove that $\|T\| = 1$, you now need to find a sequence $x$ such that $\|T(x)\|_\infty = \|x\|_\infty$. Or, for any $\epsilon > 0$, you could find a sequence $x$ such that $\|T(x)\|_\infty \ge (1-\epsilon) \|x\|_\infty$.

For problems like this, you can often track back through your work for establishing the upper bound and see how each inequality could be made an equality. For example, the inequality $$\vert x(n) \rvert \le \|x\|_\infty, \,\,\,\,\,\, n \in \mathbb N$$ becomes equality if $x$ is a constant sequence.